# foundation section tabs not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I am having an issue with foundation 4 section tabs. I copy pasted the example code to my local and tested it and it doesnt show up.

I also modified it and added some height elements to make it display properly but still I can only view on tab and clicking it doesnt actually open up the content.

I have included jquery foundation.css and foundation.min.js and also zepto.js without any luck.

If anyone could tell me what i might be doing wrong or if there is an issue with the framework that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you pls share any link or put your code in jsfiddle and share.

Answer (score -1):

Please close this.

I fixed the problem by adding a foundation at document load. :)

Cheers hope this helps someone in need.

$(document).foundation(); Thats the code I added right at the start of document.ready.

Comment: How about including that code on how you did it? that would actually help people out.